# Change CCMoveTo's destination (with ease) without stopping

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have some sprites falling from the point A to B with ease. The code:

```
id move = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:time position:new_position];
id move_ease_in = [CCEaseIn actionWithAction:[[move copy] autorelease] rate:ratio];
[sprite runAction:move_ease_in];
```

When someone taps on the screen, the sprite has to keep falling to the point C, that is below B. The sprites have to keep falling without stopping and falling again. How can I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try CCMoveBy, and add the amount of want them to move each time.

(Note that depending on the version of cocos2d that you're using, you may encounter a jerky behavior. If that is the case, check the cocos2d method definition for the move methods and comment out the flag there that has a comment "bug fix" preceding it. )

Comment: I still have the same problem: the sprite stops and then it starts the new animation. What I need is to keep the animation (the speed it had at that moment and the acceleration/ease) but it has to reach a deeper destination.

Comment: Like I said in my answer, take a look at the method definitions for CCMoveTo and CCMoveBy and see the "bug fix" for jerky motion. That might be the issue.

Comment: I'm using Cocos2D 1.0 RC3 and there's no "bug fix" in the definition of CCMoveTo or CCMoveBy.

Comment: Maybe I explained myself wrong. I call CCMoveTo to move a sprite from A to B. If I tap the screen while the sprite is between A and B, the sprite has to keep falling until it reaches C, which is deeper than B. When I tap the screen I call another CCMoveTo and the sprite goes to C, but it ignores the previous movement (its speed and acceleration/ease) and starts the second one. How can I fix this? Thanks.